# Installing magento 2.2 on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, magento2.2

I need help with magento installation on docker. I have created folder on desktop "development/sources/". After that in sources folder I have cloned repository https://github.com/php-cuong/docker-magento2-lamp. There is yaml file for docker configuration. After running docker-compose up -d command in cli, this error appears:

Recreating d817e559459e_mysql_service ...
Recreating d817e559459e_mysql_service ... error

ERROR: for d817e559459e_mysql_service  Cannot start service mysql: error while creating mount source path '/C/User                  s/Denis/Desktop/development/sources': mkdir /C/Users/Denis/Desktop: permission denied

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: error while creating mount source path '/C/Users/Denis/Desktop/devel                  opment/sources': mkdir /C/Users/Denis/Desktop: permission denied
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Mount source path that is listed in error above, was already created manually before I run that command.

Answer (score 0):

> permission denied

Right click on Docker icon in tray and select Settings.
Under "Shared Drives" mark drive "C" and apply.

Now it should work. If it doesn't, just restart Docker and it should be working.